# How do I create a Google Analytics view filter to exclude city and network domain?

Tags: google-analytics, filtering

How do I create a Google Analytics view filter to exclude two fields City and Network domain? The standard Exclude Filter only excludes 1 field

I am trying to filter out bot traffic that is coming from 
City : Ashburn
Network Domain: unknown

Other Dimensions
Browser: Chrome or Safari
Source: direct
Campaign: (not set)

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1):

Couple of quick ways to do it:

- Create a Custom Report under Customization>New Custom report, pretty intuitive and it allows to add multiple filters
- Use Google Analytics Spreadsheet Add-on